# Параметры функции выделяются последовательно?

Tags: c++

Параметры функции выделяются последовательно, или это зависит от компилятора?

Например, как можно получить указатель на переменные Эллипсиса, без использования макроса va_arg?

```
#include <iostream>

void findAverage(int first, ...)
{
    int* ptr = &first;
    
    std::cout << *(ptr + 1); // шаг 4 байта
}

int main()
{
    findAverage(0, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

По моим соображениям, если выделение параметров функции является последовательным, то код выше должен был вывести значение `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от компилятора, без `va_arg` никак.

`*(ptr + 1)` вылезает за границы переменной и вызывает неопределенное поведение.

На вашем месте, я бы забыл про `...` и использовал variadic шаблоны.